# Single Entry Linking

Tags: channel-entries

Ok, my site is made up of Cities and Properties within each city.  The usual flow is on the homepage there is a list of Cities, you click a city and it goes through to a City view which will then have a list of Properties, to which you can click through to a Property view.

Well some of my Cities only have 1 property, so I would like the link from City to go directly to the Property view, not the city view.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="city" dynamic="no" orderby="city_sort_order" sort="asc"}
                <li class="location-box colour-{city_colour}">
                    <a href="{url_title}">
                        <div class="location-box colour-{city_colour}">
                            <figure>
                                <h1>{title}</h1>
                                <img src="{city_main_image}" alt="">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Any advice?

Comment: How are the properties saved for every city? Is it a grid? A playa? Relationships?

Comment: In Property channel I have a field for Property City and that is Playa.

Comment: So, the properties aren't `children`of cities, but the cities are `children` of properties? Do I get it right?

Comment: Robson, do you want to take a look? Skype me and I'll give you access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count how many `playa:parents` the city has.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="city" dynamic="no" orderby="city_sort_order" sort="asc"}
<li class="location-box colour-{city_colour}">
    <a
    {if '{exp:playa:total_parents field="property_city"}' == 1}
        {exp:playa:parents field="property_city" var_prefix="property"}href="/{url_title}/{property:url_title}"{/exp:playa:parents}
    {if:else}
        href="/{url_title}"
    {/if}
    >
        <div class="location-box colour-{city_colour}">
            <figure>
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                <img src="{city_main_image}" alt="">
            </figure>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Please, test this code.

Answer (score 1):

count the number of properties. if the number of properties ==1 redirect to the property. How to code it exactly is upto the way you've set up the properties and cities channels

Comment: How do you mean how I have set them up?

Comment: i meant the same as the answer by Robson Sobral